# Make a PropType required for children but specify this on the parent?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a Parent component which can have different children. Children must have a `hash` prop when they are within Parent, but not if they are outside.

```
<Parent>
  // Many different components can go here
  <Something hash="#one" />
  <SomethingElse hash="#one" />
</Parent>

<App>
  <Something />
  <SomethingElse />
</App>
```

Can I define PropTypes for Parent that say that any children must have the `hash` prop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a custom validator for a propType where you can put your dynamic logic.

Sample code coming from [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) :

```
// You can also specify a custom validator. It should return an Error
// object if the validation fails. Don't `console.warn` or throw, as this
// won't work inside `oneOfType`.
customProp: function(props, propName, componentName) {
  if (!/matchme/.test(props[propName])) {
    return new Error(
      'Invalid prop `' + propName + '` supplied to' +
      ' `' + componentName + '`. Validation failed.'
    );
  }
},
```